# Filtering within a single cell using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering

I have a spreadsheet with two columns (A, and B ).

Column A is a list of funds/companies and column B is funding rounds the companies have participated.

Within each cell there is multiples values separated by a semi-colon (;).

Example:

```
Depixus, Series A, 2021 ; Egle Therapeutics, Series A, 2022 ; Amolyt Pharma, Series B, 2020.
```

My question is there a way to filter the values within a cell. Currently all the values within the cells in column B are not in year order (2022, 2021, 2020 etc).

I need to get them in descending order:

```
Egle Therapeutics, Series A, 2022 ; Depixus, Series A, 2021 ; Amolyt Pharma, Series B, 2020)
```

in an efficient quick way that doesn't involve manually redoing them.

When utilizing the formula in the answers:
[image: FUsing the formula below]

Comment: Can you put the contents of that cell in the question so we can copy paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 and TEXTSPLIT()(Currently only to insider beta channel at the time of writing):

```
=LET(arr,TRANSPOSE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,";"))),yr,RIGHT(arr,4),TEXTJOIN(" ; ",,SORTBY(arr,yr,-1)))
```

[image]

---

With current formula available in Office 365 for PC:

```
=LET(arr,TRANSPOSE(TRIM(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))),yr,RIGHT(arr,4),TEXTJOIN(" ; ",,SORTBY(arr,yr,-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Neither solution worked for me. I ended up finding a solution. I loaded the spreadsheet into power query, split it using ; as the delimiter, I then unpivoted the table, trimed to get rid of any blank cells, fed it back to excel, separated the years and then used (=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$2350=C14,$B$2:$B$2350,""))) to join them back together in the right order. It's not the easiest way but it got the job done.

Comment: @Natyrrr, I bet you are either using a Mac or the web version and are not on the beta insider track.  Which is why you are not able to use them.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya ah, another option is that the OP is Using Office 2019 which has TEXTJOIN but not LET.

Comment: @ScottCraner, not using a mac. Using a PC and not the web version. Using Microsoft 365 (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2203 Build 16.0.15028.20218) 64-bit).

Comment: @Natyrrr then the second one should work for you. as it is using only functions fully available to all office 365 pc users.

Comment: @ScottCraner, You're right it did work. There's a much larger formatting issue in this spreadsheet (semi-colons missing) but for the most part, it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is what I have ***tried***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

Using Two **O365 Insiders Beta Channel** Functions -- `TEXTSPLIT()` & `HSTACK()` with **Regular O365 Functions** with `LET()` , `TEXTJOIN()` & `SORT()` Functions,

• Formula used in cell **A5**

```
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),," ; "),b,RIGHT(a,4)+0,c,HSTACK(a,b),
TEXTJOIN(" ; ",,INDEX(SORT(c,2,-1),,1))&".")
```

---

Using **O365** Functions --> `LET()`, `TEXTJOIN()` & `SORT()`, with **Regular** Excel Functions, `FILTERXML()` & `CHOOSE()`

• Formula used in cell **A13**

```
=LET(a,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")," ; ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),
b,RIGHT(a,4)/1,TEXTJOIN(" ; ",,INDEX(SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},a,b),2,-1),,1))&".")
```